# Generate random string and save to file

Tags: ruby, file, random, save

I'm stuck doing so simple program in Ruby that would generate a 63 characters long random string and then storing it in a text file.
For now my code is :

```
def Password_Generator(length=63)
  chars = ("a".."z").to_a + ("A".."Z").to_a + ("0".."9").to_a
  password = ''
  length.time { |i| password << chars[rand(chars.length)] }
  aFile = File.new("Generated-Password.txt", "w+")
  aFile.write(password)
  aFile.close
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'securerandom'
def generate_password(length=63)
  # urlsafe_base64 uses lowercase, uppercase, 1-9 and _-. 
  # The latter are removed from the generated string.
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(length).delete('_-')[0, length]
end

File.open('pwd.txt', 'w'){|f| f.puts generate_password}
```

Answer (score 4):

First off, `Password_Generator` is a bad method name in Ruby, since constants are used for class names. Also Ruby developers prefer snake_case over camelCase. For your actual question (it's Ruby 1.9):

```
def generate_password(length=63)
  chars = [*?a..?z, *?A..?Z, *0..9]
  (1..length).map{ chars.sample }.join
end
```

I'd probably do the actual writing to a file in a different method, separation of concerns and all that.

Comment: WoW I really don't understand that way of generating random strings Oo ! Never saw that *?a. Could you post the write file function ? Thx for your quick answer !

Comment: for writing to the file use `File.open("generated-password.txt','w+'){|w| w.write generate_password }`

Comment: I tested it and it worked ! Thanks you very much to you two for the help ! And thanks your for the *?a way of generating randoms !

Comment: `*` in this context is the splat operator (`[*1..3] #=> [1, 2, 3]`). `?a` is a character literal, so we are splatting a range of characters (`[*?a..?e] #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]`). @Jacob showed you a way to write to the file.

Comment: Glad to help. BTW: if this was the answer you were looking for, please accept it so other people know it's been sufficiently answered. That's considered good practice here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: No, you upvoted it. Accepting is done via the little tick mark below the vote count and arrows.